# Traer el ultimo registro de pago de cada cliente

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos

He intentado subconsultas uniendo las 3 tablas que ocupo y nada

Con Subconsultas no me ha funcionado y lo que mas se acerca es utilizando `MAX` pero igual, solo me trae la fecha de vencimiento y el tipo de inscripción del ultimo pago registrado CORRECTO, pero los demás campos no.

Ya intenté añadirles `MAX` a los otros campos pero no me funciona. Gracias de antemano si me pueden ayudar.

Estos son todos los registros que tengo en `pagos_cliente`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esta sería mi consulta para traer el ultimo registro de pago:

```
SELECT p.nombre, c.id_cliente, d.tipo_documento, m.tipo_matricula, pd.tipo_descuento, MAX(i.tipo_inscripcion) as tipo_inscripcion, pc.pago_matricula, pc.id_descuento, pc.pago_descuento, pc.id_inscripcion, MAX(pc.pago_inscripcion) as pago_inscripcion, MAX(pc.pago_total) as pago_total, pc.fecha_ultimo_pago, MAX(pc.fecha_vencimiento) as fecha_vencimiento FROM tbl_personas as p
LEFT JOIN tbl_clientes as c ON p.id_personas = c.id_persona
LEFT JOIN tbl_documento as d ON p.id_documento = d.id_documento
LEFT JOIN tbl_matricula as m ON c.id_matricula = m.id_matricula
LEFT JOIN tbl_pagos_cliente as pc ON c.id_cliente = pc.id_cliente
LEFT JOIN tbl_inscripcion as i ON pc.id_inscripcion = i.id_inscripcion
LEFT JOIN tbl_descuento as pd ON pc.id_descuento = pd.id_descuento
WHERE c.tipo_cliente = 'Gimnasio'
GROUP BY c.id_cliente
```

Esto es lo que me devuelve:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me devuelve la `fecha_vencimiento` correcta y el `tipo_inscripcion` correcto pero lo demas no, por ejemplo: `ALEX FRANCO` debería de salirme en el `pago_inscripcion` y `pago_total: 180`

Comment: Juan Rivera sos un crack me has ayudado un monton, ya me funciona, Te agradezco

Comment: Lo pondre como respuesta, pero como te dije, "es una solucion rapida". Puede haber otras formas mejores de hacer lo que quieres

Comment: Entiendo, por ahora lo dejare asi, muchas gracias

Answer (score 1):

Una solucion rapida seria agregando una subconsulta a tu `WHERE`. Asi:

```
WHERE c.tipo_cliente = 'Gimnasio' AND pc.fecha_ultimo_pago = (SELECT MAX(fecha_ultimo_pago) FROM tbl_pagos_cliente as pc1 WHERE pc1.id_cliente = pc.id_cliente)
```

La explicacion es simple, la subconsulta obtiene la `ultima fecha_ultimo_pago` de un cliente para que asi se filtre por los datos que quieres